# Can a string without white space be considered a valid JSON?

Tags: json, api, rest, validation, parsing

I'm using JsonParser.parseString which is passing if i give a value like "1234" or "abcd" (ignore case). Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is valid JSON for a number. Using JavaScript's parser:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('1234'));
```

It seems unlikely to me that a JSON parser was happy with your second example, because it's not valid:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('abcd'));
```

...unless it actually had quotes around it, in which case it's valid JSON for a string:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('"abcd"'));
```

But even objects don't have to have whitespace, for instance:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"example":"object"}'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using JsonParser.parseString which is passing if i give a value like "1234" or "abcd" (ignore case). Can anyone explain this?

The [current specification for application/json](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json) is [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259)

Highlights from the production rules:

```
JSON-text = ws value ws
value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string
number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]
int = zero / ( digit1-9 *DIGIT )

string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
```

Therefore:

A sequence of digits (ex: 1234) is a valid JSON-text

A sequence of digits enclosed in double quotes (ex: "1234") is a valid JSON-text

A sequence of "unescaped" characters enclosed in double quotes (ex: "abcd") is a valid JSON-text

A sequence of "unescaped" characters without enclosing double quotes (ex: abcd) is *not* a valid JSON-text.

---

```
cat <<TEST | jq .
"abcd"
TEST
```

```
"abcd"
```

```
cat <<TEST | jq .
abcd  
TEST
```

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```